# Delete <li>'s that have the same value in another <li>

Tags: javascript

If there were two `<ul>`'s, one called `list_a` and the other called `list_b`, using javascript and not using any libraries like jQuery, how would you delete the `<li>`'s in `list_a` that have the same value as those in `list_b`?

Heres the example HTML:

```
  <ul id="list_a">
    <li value="1">list_a_0</li>
    <li value="8">list_a_8</li>
    <li value="9">list_a_9</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="list_b">
    <li value="8">list_b_8</li>
    <li value="9">list_b_9</li>
    <li value="2">list_b_2</li>
  </ul>
```

The end result should be:

```
  <ul id="list_a">
    <li value="1">list_a_0</li>
    <!-- DELETED TWO <li>'s -->
  </ul>

  <ul id="list_b">
    <li value="8">list_b_8</li>
    <li value="9">list_b_9</li>
    <li value="2">list_b_2</li>
  </ul>
```

The javascript so far that I can build (that doesn't work) is:

```
window.onload=function()
{
  init();

  function init()
  {
    var listA = document.getElementById("list_a");

    for(var i in listA.childNodes)
    {
      var x = listA.childNodes[i];
      var listB = document.getElementById("list_b");

      for(var j in listB.childNodes)
      {
        var y = listB.childNodes[j];
        if(x.innerHTML == y.innerHTML)
          listA.removeChild(listA);
      }
    }          
  }  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `listA.removeChild(listA);` should be `listA.removeChild(x);` I believe. Looks like that should be enough. Although... `.innerHTML` will never be the same, because the content of the list items differ. Try comparing their `.value` in stead, see if that suits your needs.

Comment: I'm curious about the use-case for this. It can be done, but your problem clearly lies elsewhere (why are you having to fix this in JS)!

Comment: Don't use innerhtml, use textnode and it's value. Also, just keep a hash of encountered values, if the value exists already then remove that node and move onto the next one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rmXrZ/

```
window.onload = function() {

    var listA = document.getElementById("list_a");
    var listB = document.getElementById("list_b");

    for (var i = 0; i < listA.children.length; i++) {
        var x = listA.children[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < listB.children.length; j++) {
            var y = listB.children[j];
            if (x.value == y.value) {
                listA.removeChild(x);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Don't use `for-in` for iteration of numeric indices
- Cache the DOM selection instead of re-selecting in the loop
- Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` to avoid text nodes between elements
- Compare `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`
- Remove `x` instead of `listA`
- When an element is removed from `listA`, decrement `i`, because removal from the DOM means removal from the `.children` collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function init() {
    var listA = document.getElementById("list_a");
    var listB = document.getElementById("list_b");

    for(var i =0; i<listA.children.length;i++) {
      var x = listA.children[i];

      for(var j in listB.children) {      
        var y = listB.children[j];
        if(x.value == y.value)
           x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
      }
    }          
  }
```

Avoid hitting the DOM on multiple occasions, also in this case children is a better choice of data.